# Spectral Inclusion

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space, $B(H)$ be the set of all bounded linear operators on $H$. An operator $A$ in $B(H)$ is said to be positive if $\langle Ax, x\rangle > 0$ $\forall x \in H,$ where $\langle,\rangle$ is the inner product in $H$. Also $A,B \in B(H)$ is said to commute if $(AB)x = (BA)x$ $\forall x \in H$. Let $\sigma(A)$ denote the spectrum of $A$. The question is whether we have the following relation: Let $A,B \in B(H)$ such that they are positive and they commute. Then, $$\sigma(AB) \subset \sigma(A)\sigma(B).$$

Comment: Did you mean your question to include $A,B$ being positive? If not, why did you include the definition of positive operators?

Comment: Yes $A,B$ should be positive. I will edit the question, thank you

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts?  Generally pure problem statement questions (PSQs) are frowned upon here, we want to see some evidence of your own work first

Comment: This result holds in complex Banach Algebra without the assumption of positivity. Here the space we have taken becomes a real Banach algebra and that is why the result doesnot hold directly. Suppose we take A = [[0, -1],[1,0]], B = [[0,1],[-1,0]] both 2x2 matrices, then AB is identity hence, spectrum AB = {1} while spectrum(A) = spectrum(B) = {}. This is the reason why I insisted on positivity. If A,B where taken to be positive, then such a problem won't arise (I concluded this with the examples I tried with). I need a rigorous proof here.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $\mathcal{A}$ is a unital and abelian Banach Algebra, then $\sigma(AB)\subset\sigma(A)\sigma(B)$ for all $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$.

To see this, note that in general
$$\sigma(X)=\{\phi(X): \phi\in\Omega(\mathcal{A})\},$$
where $\Omega(\mathcal{A})$ denotes the character space of $\mathcal{A}$, i.e. $\phi\in\Omega(\mathcal{A})$ if and only if $\phi:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a non-zero $*$-homomorphism. Now
$$\sigma(AB)=\{\phi(AB):\phi\in\Omega(\mathcal{A})\}=\{\phi(A)\phi(B):\phi\in\Omega(\mathcal{A})\}\subset\{\phi(A):\phi\}\cdot\{\phi(B):\phi\}=\sigma(A)\sigma(B)$$
Your problem follows by considering $\mathcal{A}$ to be the $C^*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$ generated by $1_H,A,B$. This is commutative since the generators commute and since the spectrum is invariant by passing to unital $C^*$-subalgebras, you get your result.

Comment: Here, I have taken real Banach Algebra, so the inclusion need not hold for all A,B in it as you said. For this consider the 2x2 matrices A = [[0, -1],[1,0]], B = [[0,1],[-1,0]]. Then AB is identity hence, spectrum AB = {1} while spectrum(A) = spectrum(B) = {}. This is the reason why I insisted on positivity. If A,B where taken to be positive, then such a problem won't arise (I concluded this with the examples I tried with).

Comment: @AnmaryTonny Oh okay I didn't notice. I will think about it a bit more.